# Swift program never enters CompletionHandler for a dataTask

Tags: swift, asynchronous, urlsession

I am in the process of implementing a REST API with Swift. Of course, part of this API is using HTTP requests to retrieve and send data.

Full disclosure, I am inexperienced with Swift and am using this as a learning project to get my feet wet, so to speak. But it's turned into much more of a difficult project than I anticipated.

In implementing the first get method, I have (finally) gotten rid of all the compilation errors. However, when I call the function which utilizes the URLRequest, URLSession, dataTask, etc, it is never entered.

Upon debugging the program, I can watch the program execution reach the CompletionHandler, and skip over it right to "task.resume()."

A similar construction works in a Swift Playground, but does not work in the actual project proper.

So far I have tried a few things, namely making the function access a class instance variable, in hopes that that would force it to execute. But it does not.

I think the issue may be dealing with synchronicity, and perhaps I need to use a Semaphore, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious first.

```swift
import Foundation
/**
 A class to wrap all GET and POST requests, to avoid the necessity of repeatedly writing request code in each API method.
 */
class BasicRequest {
    private var url: URL
    private var header: [String: String]
    private var responseType: String

    private var jsonResponse: Any?


    init(url: URL, header: [String: String], responseType: String) {
        self.url = url
        self.header = header
        self.responseType = responseType
    } //END INIT

    public func requestJSON() -> Any {
        // Create the URLRequest object, and fill the header with the header fields as provided.
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: self.url)
        for (value, key) in self.header {
            urlRequest.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            print("Entered the completion handler")
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 200 == httpResponse.statusCode else {
                print("HTTP Request unsuccessful")
                return
            }
            guard let mime = response?.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
                print("Not a JSON response")
                return
            }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                print(json)
                self.jsonResponse = json
            } catch {
                print("Could not transform to JSON")
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        return "Function has returned"
    } //END REQUESTJSON
}
```

The expected result would be returning a JSON object, however that does not seem to be the case.

With respect to error messages, I get none. The only log I get in the debugger is the boilerplate "process exited with code 0."

To be truthful, I'm at a loss with what is causing this not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're writing this in a command-line app. In that case the program is terminating before the URLRequest completes.

> I think the issue may be dealing with synchronicity, and perhaps I need to use a Semaphore, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious first.

Exactly.

The typical tool in Swift is `DispatchGroup`, which is just a higher-level kind of semaphore. Call `dispatchGroup.enter()` before starting the request, and all `dispatchGroup.leave()` at the end of the completion handler. In your calling code, include `dispatchGroup.wait()` to wait for it. (If that's not clear, I can add code for it, but there are also a lot of SO answers you can find that will demonstrate it.)

Comment: That sounds perfect, I'll give that a try. Thank you so much!